# Custom Command Class with WPF (without ViewModel link)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, commandbinding

*In context of :*
.NET Core WPF application

*I would like to :*
Create custom Command Class

*for what :*
Binding basic custom action on Button click

I try lot of things but I always error generated in compilation.
Can you help me to create this concept of code ?

*My XAML window :*

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MyApp" Height="800" Width="1200"
        BorderThickness="5"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        xmlns:test="clr-namespace:MyApp.Command"
>
    
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="test:MyCustomCommand" CanExecute="CanExecute" Executed="Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
            
    <Button Name="CreateOperation" Command="test:MyCustomCommand" Grid.Column="0" Width="70" Height="25" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock>NEW</TextBlock>
     </Button>
           
</Window>
```

*MyCustomCommand.cs class :*

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyApp.Command;

public class MyCustomCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public MyCustomCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object obj)
    {
        
    }
    
    public void Executed(object parameter)
    {
        
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In this context the CanExecute and Executed method declaration in XAML Command Binding is not found.

**For me and all others that need help to create theirs custom class Command WPF, can you help me to find correct syntax for running command into custom class ?**

Comment: It is unclear what your exact problem is and what exactly CommandBinding has to do with it. You could simply add a property of type MyCustomCommand to your MainWindow class and bind to it like `<Button Command="{Binding TheCommandProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" .../>`. No view model required.

Comment: You would of course have to fix your MyCustomCommand implementation, or you use the standard RelayCommand or DelegateCommand classes that are available on the internet. To fix yours, the CanExecute method must call `return _canExecute(obj);` and the Execute method must call `_execute(obj);`

Comment: *"but I always error generated in compilation"* - Where is the error message?? When you need help to resolve a compiletime error you *must* provide the error message. the error message tells exactly what's wrong. If you are not able to understand the message then somebody could explain it to you - if you had posted the message. CommandBinding is supposed to work with routed commands. The `CommandBinding.CanExecute` and `CommandBinding.Executed` properties are not referring to the `ICommand` members. They are events.

Comment: In your case the compiler is not able to find the code-behind event handlers that you named "CanExecute" and "Executed". See this [example (Microsoft Relaying Command Logic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) to learn how to properly implement an ICommand.

Comment: See [Commanding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#commandbinding) to learn how to correctly use CommandBinding and commands in general..

Comment: Also *"`Command="test:MyCustomCommand"`"* does not work. You would have to define a binding. For example `Command="{Binding MyCustomCommand}"` (depending on the current DataContext). Your syntax (without a binding) would work if `test:MyDefiningClass.MyCustomCommand` is a static `RoutedCcommand` field (e.g. defined in `MyDefiningClass`): `Command="test:MyDefiningClass.MyCustomCommand"`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the Window.CommandBindings. Also remove path to the command - test:. The command will be located in MainWindow code-behind as you requested. To pass a parameter to the command use CommandParameter property of the Button.

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        Name="_mainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MyApp" Height="800" Width="1200"
        BorderThickness="5"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        xmlns:test="clr-namespace:MyApp.Command">
    
    <Button Name="CreateOperation" Command="{Binding MyCustomCommand, ElementName=_mainWindow}" Grid.Column="0" Width="70" Height="25" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock>NEW</TextBlock>
     </Button>
           
</Window>
```

Add default constructor to the MyCustomCommand class.

And the MainWindow code-behind should look like this:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ICommand _myCustomCommand = null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public ICommand MyCustomCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_myCustomCommand == null)
                    _myCustomCommand = new MyCustomCommand();
                return _myCustomCommand;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"`Command="MyCustomCommand"`"* - How is this supposed to work? Properties defined on a DependencyObject (like Window) that serve as a binding source (or target) must be dependency properties. Otherwise you will create a memory leak. Also because dependency properties don't require reflection in order to resolve the binding's property path they perform best.